# JavaScript to clear incorrect data from a textfield

Tags: javascript, date, textfield

I am trying to do a date field similar to the one here in javascript:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/validatedate.shtml

How can I clear the field when an incorrect date or year is entered but keep the month and/or date that were entered correctly?

Comment: so far I can clear the entire month, date, and year when an incorrect year is entered and return focus back to the text field or when an incorrect date is entered clear the month and date or when an incorrect month is entered clear the month

Answer (score 0):

The linked script simply returns true or false depending on whether the entire date is valid or not, it doesn't tell you which bit is invalid.

If a user enters an invalid date, you can remove the value by setting the input's value to '' (empty string), something like:

```
var input = /* reference to input */;
if (!checkdate(input.value)) {
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
}
```

But that is really annoying, the user may have made a small mistake and would rather fix it than type the entire date again.